# TCP packet is not dropped even though the size is over MSS of the receiver

Tags: tcp

I tested to simultate packet drop when the packet size is over MSS(maximum segment size) determined by TCP handshake.
So, I modified the MTU of server from 1500(default) to 1350 by using `ifconfig ens3 mtu 1350 up`. According to the tcpdump, this is configured well. In No 22, MSS is 1310.
When client sends large packet, some of them will be fragmented. However, we as can see in No 28, even though the fragmented length is 1460, the packet was not dropped. I expected that the packet will be dropped in the server side.
The client has fixed size MTU(1500) to send packet to destination.(actually, the client is netscaler switch)

Does anyone know, why the packet is not dropped?

client port : 8156 (MTU 1500)

server port : 19192 (MTU 1350)

```
     22 2023-10-30 01:42:55.891345    10.192.252.248        10.191.101.119        TCP      62     0          8156 → 19192 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8190 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256
     23 2023-10-30 01:42:55.891391    10.191.101.119        10.192.252.248        TCP      62     0          19192 → 8156 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1310 WS=512
     24 2023-10-30 01:42:55.891592    10.192.252.248        10.191.101.119        TCP      54     0          8156 → 19192 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=7936 Len=0
     25 2023-10-30 01:42:55.893093    10.192.252.248        10.191.101.119        TCP      1364   1310       8156 → 19192 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262656 Len=1310 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
     26 2023-10-30 01:42:55.893132    10.191.101.119        10.192.252.248        TCP      54     0          19192 → 8156 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1311 Win=68608 Len=0
     27 2023-10-30 01:42:55.893154    10.192.252.248        10.191.101.119        TCP      204    150        8156 → 19192 [ACK] Seq=1311 Ack=1 Win=262656 Len=150 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
     28 2023-10-30 01:42:55.893154    10.192.252.248        10.191.101.119        TCP      1514   1460       8156 → 19192 [ACK] Seq=1461 Ack=1 Win=262656 Len=1460 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
     29 2023-10-30 01:42:55.893154    10.192.252.248        10.191.101.119        HTTP     361    307        GET / HTTP/1.1 
     30 2023-10-30 01:42:55.893182    10.191.101.119        10.192.252.248        TCP      54     0          19192 → 8156 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=3228 Win=72192 Len=0
     31 2023-10-30 01:42:55.893972    10.191.101.119        10.192.252.248        HTTP     905    851        HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (text/html)
     32 2023-10-30 01:42:55.897581    10.192.252.248        10.191.101.119        TCP      54     0          8156 → 19192 [FIN, ACK] Seq=3228 Ack=852 Win=261888 Len=0
     33 2023-10-30 01:42:55.897681    10.191.101.119        10.192.252.248        TCP      54     0          19192 → 8156 [FIN, ACK] Seq=852 Ack=3229 Win=72192 Len=0
     34 2023-10-30 01:42:55.898707    10.192.252.248        10.191.101.119        TCP      54     0          8156 → 19192 [ACK] Seq=3229 Ack=853 Win=261888 Len=0
```